# Cual es la sentencia SQL para insertar datos en mi Base de Datos en MySQL en Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

En mi programa usando Java en Eclipse y MySQL, tengo los siguientes datos:

- Número de llamada (int): callcenter.getTotalLlamadas()
- Tipo de llamada (string): Local
- Número de Origen (string): txtNumeroDeOrigen.getText()
- Número de Destino (string): txtNumeroDeDestino.getText()
- Duración (int): Integer.parseInt(txtDuracion.getText())

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Bases de Datos y estoy confundido a la hora de insertar estos datos a mi tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según leí en Internet, hasta ahora tengo esto pero, no funciona, Eclipse lo marca en rojo diciendo que es incorrecto:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO llamadas (ID, Tipo, NumeroOrigen, NumeroDestino, Duracion, Precio) values ('"+ callcenter.getTotalLlamadas() +"', Local, '"txtNumeroDeOrigen.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", "")"', '"txtNumeroDeDestino.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", "")"', '"txtDuracion.getText()"', '"callLocal.calcularPrecio()"')";
```

Cuál es la sentencia correcta para poder enviar los datos obtenidos mediante mis campos JFormattedTextField?, el único dato que es fijo es el Tipo, el cual es "Local", este no lo pido.

Gracias y saludos, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: *hasta ahora tengo esto pero, no funciona*: ¿Puedes ser más específico? ¿Recibes algún error? ¿En qué sentido no funciona? Lo que sí te puedo decir de una vez es que por un sinnumero de razones, es preferible no concatenar los valores directamente en la cadena SQL. Es mejor parametrizar los valores.

Comment: Simplemente, esa línea Eclipse lo marca en rojo, diciendo que es incorrecto, no me ofrece mas detalles, no sé si es la forma correcta de hacerlo insertando las variables directamente en la sentencia SQL. A parametrizar te refieres a usar comodines?, ejemplo: (?, ?,. .....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente sentencia preparada, la cual sirve para enviar sentencias SQL a la base de datos.:

```html
String query = "INSERT INTO llamadas (ID, Tipo, NumeroOrigen, NumeroDestino, Duracion, Precio)"
        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setInt (1, callcenter.getTotalLlamadas());
preparedStmt.setString (2, "Local");
preparedStmt.setString (3, txtNumeroDeOrigen.getText());
preparedStmt.setString (4, txtNumeroDeDestino.getText());
preparedStmt.setString (5, txtDuracion.getText());
preparedStmt.setInt (6, callLocal.calcularPrecio());

preparedStmt.execute();
```

Comment: Perfecto, voy a probarlo ahora. O sea que no es necesario poner INSERT INTO.... ejemplo: INSERT INTO llamadas (ID, Tipo, NumeroOrigen, NumeroDestino, Duracion, Precio) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). Pensé que era obligatorio.

Comment: disculpa si es necesario ponerlo deja lo corrijo

Comment: Perfecto, gracias J. Castro, voy a probar enseguida. Te lo agradezco.

Comment: @RobertGomez para eso es la comunidad para ayudar en lo que se pueda

Comment: una última pregunta, hay diferencia en usar PreparedStatement que CreateStatement? y también execute que executeUpdate?, o es la misma cosa?.